# Configuring and using Multiple Queues

Tags: c#, configuration, startup, hangfire

i'm in trouble with configuring and using multiple queues.

Here is the content of my startup class:

```
var options = new DashboardOptions
        {
            AppPath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~")
        };
        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/jobs", options);

        var queues = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
        {
            Queues = new[] { "high", "normal" }
        };

        app.UseHangfireServer(queues);
```

The server starts correctly and from the dashboard i can see the queues.

But when I try to enqueue a process, hangfire always sets the jobs into the default queue.
This is the call to the method:

```
BackgroundJob
 .Enqueue<IFileConverterService>(
  x => x.CreateSlides(docId, folderpath, priority));
```

This is the method implementation:

```
public class FileConverterService : IFileConverterService
{
    [Queue("high")]
   public void CreateSlides(Guid documentId, string folderPath, int priority)
   {
       //my stuff
   }
}
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem.

In the startup configuration it seems it's mandatory to define a default queue as shown

```
 var queues = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
            {
                Queues = new[] { "high", "default" }
            };
```

Then implement a method with the Queue attribute and another one without it.

```
    [Queue("high")]
    public void CreateSlidesWithHighPriority(Guid documentId, string folderPath, int priority)
    {
       //my code
    }

    public void CreateSlidesWithLowPriority(Guid documentId, string folderPath, int priority)
    {
        //my code
    }
```

Now all works perfectly.